# A Mealy machine state diagram ( Couldn't draw it )

Tags: diagram

I want to draw a state diagram of a Mealy synchronous state machine having a single input x, and a single output y, such that y is asserted if the ***total number of 1’s received is a multiple of 3.***

But the problem is how to get a multiple of 3 only with one input and one output ??

Help appreciated

Comment: Does n`t this mean "If the input sequence is 1 then 1 then 1 assert  Y" ?

Comment: Do you think the problem is to determine if a binary number is divisible by three or is it to determine if the number of 1s in a string adds up to 3, 6, 9, etc.?  As an example 7 has three 1s in it but is not divisible by 3.  Which is it?

Comment: @owg60 not divisible it's multiple ( I don't the difference but it's not correct if it's divisible) the problem is how to draw it as for your Question the number of 1's is the matter for example 1 then 1 then 1 then y would be asserted cause it's multiple of 3

Comment: Draw four state bubbles.  Label the first one init, the second one, the third two, and the last three.  From init transition to one if x is 1 otherwise stay in init.  Do the same for one to two.  Do the same from two to three but output is 1 on the transition.  From three go back to one for x=1.  Otherwise stay in three.  If you post a picture, i'll let you know if it is right.

Comment: @owg60 here you go  ( https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0dJBo-zapNqNmt6YUp1a1pGMWc/view?usp=sharing )

Comment: @owg60 but when it goes from 2 to 3 how it return to 1 ??

Comment: Did you answer your own question about going from 2 to 3 and returning a 1?

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt is close.  Here is one way to do it;

[image: Mealy]